# Does text-decoration:none override font-weight:900?

Tags: html, css, fonts, bold, text-decorations

I'm using monospace fonted text for hyperlinks in my menu. In order to eliminate the underline, I used text-decoration:none. Will this prevent me from making the font bolder?

http://www.fccorp.us/index.php -> the text in the blue boxes on the left.

Comment: No; `text-decoration` and `font-weight` are entirely different properties, hence the different names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The monospace font just doesn't look particularly different when it's bolded. Try setting it to Courier instead.

Comment: What a monospace font looks like when bolded depends on the font, on the rendering engine, and other things. Using Courier is a bad move; Courier does not look good, especially on some old systems where real Courier (a bitmap font) is used – modern Windows systems map Courier to Courier New.

Comment: All good points - though when I said "monospace font" I was referring to the font-family "Monospace," which s/he had chosen to use originally. To the OP, most designers would probably suggest avoiding any monospaced fonts unless there's a reason they need to be monospaced. In that case, Courier New is probably your best bet other than downloading and embedding a custom font.

Answer (score 0):

No. Text decoration has no effect on font weight.

Answer (score 0):

No `text-decoration` doesn't have any effect on `font-weight`. They are two entirely different properties.

Answer (score 0):

It will not. Font weight is not affected by decoration. Link to jsfiddle in comments